# How to correctly notify this adapter its dataset has changed?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, gridview, notifydatasetchanged

I am `asynchronously` downloading images that will be part of a `GridView`. And to update the `GridView` within the `onCreate()`, I call `notifyDataSetChanged();` on a `runOnUiThread();`

Now, my question is:

Is there a better way to do this? I am setting the `Thread` to sleep for 2 seconds to ensure the images will be there the time the data in the adapter gets changed. But, of course, I am hardcoding this condition (It may take more than 2 seconds), and the internet connection might fail preventing the `GridView` update correctly.

Here is the `Thread`,

```
private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        updateData(); // contains notifyDataSetChanged()
        if(images[0] == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
"Your Internet Connection is not working properly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                 
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

};
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: you cannot update ui from a thread other than ui thread. What does updateData do?

Comment: Well, it is a ui thread. `UpdateData()` sets the data from the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AsyncTask` class. It has three important abstract functions.
`doInBackground
onPostExecute
onPreExecute`

You can search about this on internet and also can check this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html).

Comment: You are right. Even though I am using an `AsyncTask`, I totally forgot about `onPostExecute`. That is so much better than the `Thread`. Thanks!